# Not able to translate OK and cancel buttons in confirmation popup minicart

Tags: magento2.2.2, mini-cart, popup, inline-translations

After adding an item into cart if we goto mini cart and click on remove item a confirmation popup with `Ok` and `Cancel` option will appear. I am not able to translate the `Ok` and `Cancel` buttons.

Please guide me how to do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: On which language you want to translate?

Comment: to german and french

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: No, i didn't get the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Minicart confirmation popup button text `Ok` and `Cancel` option comes to the below file path. You can able to find that two button text form there.

> File path:
>   magento/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/modal/confirm.js

```
buttons: [{
    text: $t('Cancel'),
    class: 'action-secondary action-dismiss',

    /**
     * Click handler.
     */
    click: function (event) {
        this.closeModal(event);
    }
}, {
    text: $t('OK'),
    class: 'action-primary action-accept',

    /**
     * Click handler.
     */
    click: function (event) {
        this.closeModal(event, true);
    }
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/17193
Magento 2.3.0. This fix cant resolve the issue for me.
I fixed it via adding translation in template and variables:

> vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/templates/modal/modal-popup.html

```
        <footer class="modal-footer">
        <% _.each(data.buttons, function(button) { %>
        <button
            class="<%- button.class %>"
            type="button"
            data-role="action"><span><%= jQuery.mage.__(button.text) %></span></button>
        <% }); %>
    </footer>
```

and

> vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/modal/confirm.js

```
], function ($, _, $t) {
'use strict';

var cancelBtn = $t('Cancel');
var okBtn = $t('Ok');
```

and then

```
            buttons: [{
            text: cancelBtn,
            class: 'action-secondary action-dismiss',

            /**
             * Click handler.
             */
            click: function (event) {
                this.closeModal(event);
            }
        }, {
            text: okBtn,
            class: 'action-primary action-accept',
```