# Where i can find these 2 buttons in magento 2 i want to translate these buttons

Tags: magento2, language, popup

[image]

Where i can find these 2 buttons in magento 2 i want to translate these buttons

Comment: Refer the answer. You have help full for same

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/233336/not-able-to-translate-ok-and-cancel-buttons-in-confirmation-popup-minicart/276981#276981

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add translation against these button text in this:

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/i18n/en_Us.csv
```

**Note: File name would depend upon your required language**

Then add these lines in file:

```
"Ok","[NEW_OK_TEXT]"
"Cancel","[NEW_CANCEL_TEXT]"
```

After deployment this will work:

```
php -dmemory_limit=1G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: That's great. Please vote answer and mark it correct if it is working

Comment: please tell me how i can translate cancel word what syntax used?

Comment: Already in answer, in your csv add this line `"Cancel","[NEW_CANCEL_TEXT]"` and after deployment it will work

Comment: @JunaidAshfaq you said my answer worked for you and mark other answer. Please mark my answer correct if it is helpful to you, so that it would be helpful for others in future

Answer (score 0):

check with below part,content exist there.

`File path: magento/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/modal/confirm.js`

```
buttons: [{
    text: $t('Cancel'),
    class: 'action-secondary action-dismiss',

    /**
     * Click handler.
     */
    click: function (event) {
        this.closeModal(event);
    }
}, {
    text: $t('OK'),
    class: 'action-primary action-accept',

    /**
     * Click handler.
     */
    click: function (event) {
        this.closeModal(event, true);
    }
}]
```

I hope its work for you.